# How to check if my button is selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

If my button is in the "selected" state, I want an activity indicator to appear to let the user know that something is happening and that my app is searching for data. I've tried to accomplish this FIRST by using NSLog to see if I can get this method working FIRST. So I did this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
searchedItem.delegate = self;

if(searchButton.selected == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"The button was selected");
}



}
```

For some reason, it won't work.

Comment: try with isSelected method

Comment: i dont think what you want is something happening when the button is in the state `selected`. it sounds more like you are searching for a regular listener to a button click?

Comment: use BOOL function for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this checkmark in your button click event. It perfect work when click on button as first time then got to **Not Selected** and after click on second time go to  **Selected**.

```
-(IBAction)ClickBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        NSLog(@" Not Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@" Selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean make the connection to this button from the UI?

Comment: @KiritModi amazing answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
searchedItem.delegate = self;

[searchButton setSelected:YES];

if(searchButton.selected == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"The button was selected");
}


}
```